# how to empty search box on click event in wenzhixin bootstrap table without refresh page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-table

I want to empty search box. when I click anywhere on a page then without refresh page I want to get an only empty search box in a wenzhixin bootstrap table

```
 <table id="view_table" data-toggle="table" 
      data-search="true"
      data-page-list="[5, 10, 20]"
      data-page-size="5"
      data-pagination="true"
      data-show-pagination-switch="true" >
 <thead>
    <tr class="table-heading">
       <th data-field="image"><h4>Image</h4></th>
       <th data-field="name"><h4>Name</h4></th>
    </tr>
 </thead>

   <tbody>


   </tbody>
</table>
<button id="empty_search" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
 <script>
    $('#empty_search').on('click', function(){
        $.(this.["data-search"]).empty();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `this.["data-search"]` makes no sense to begin with. Apart from that `this` probably isn’t what you expect it to be in that context, the syntax is bogus as well - it is either `foo.bar` or `foo[bar]` - but not dot _and_ square brackets.

Comment: try to use `$( this ).data( "search", '' )` instead of `$.(this.["data-search"]).empty()`

Comment: @Stranger, yes I tried but not work.

Comment: @misorude, $('#empty_search').on('click', function(){
                          $("#view_table[data-search]").empty() 
                     });
is right?

Comment: That would select the `table` element in your example (because it has that id, and has an attribute named `data-search`) - but I doubt you actually want to “empty” the whole table(?). You are talking about a search field, but there is no such thing in the code you have shown above. If that field gets created dynamically by another script, then use your browser dev tools to inspect it and find out what id (or other characteristics suitable for selection, if necessary) it has. And to empty an input field, the right method would be setting the value to an empty string.

Comment: `$( '#view_table' ).data( "search", '' );` it works fine for me (jquery needed)

Comment: @misorude, sir in wenzhixin bootstrap table data-search=" true" is work as a search box so we don't create any search box. if we do data-search="false" so search box automatically disable and not show.

Comment: @Stranger, sir $( '#view_table' ).data( "search", '' ); this is still not working.

Comment: _“in wenzhixin bootstrap table data-search=" true" is work as a search box”_ - a mere table _by itself_ doesn’t allow the user to input anything to search, so what this attribute does is probably instruct some script to automatically _generate_ a search input field based on this.

Comment: Looks like you are using this here, http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/ - so you should not mess around with trying to empty any form fields on your own to begin with, but simply call the method this provides to clear the search: http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#methods/resetSearch.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on the clear button so search box value reset and you search again new fresh data.

```
$('#clear').on("click",function() {
     $('#bootstrap_table_ID').bootstrapTable("resetSearch","");
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/9ynp8j6k/1/

You can empty the form field like this:

```
$('#clear').on("click",function() {
    $('.bootstrap-table .form-control').val("");
});
```

Comment: When I clicked anywhere in a table so table data did not reset and same data display or no record found a message to show.